# Fuzzy search over encrypted data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a schema where couple of fields must be encrypted. I was wondering if someone has done it or can point me to a resource to know if with elasticsearch I have a way to implement a fuzzy search over this encrypted data.

For example when I have

```
{ 
  "last_name": "encryptedLastName",
}
```

and 2 documents where lastName was encrypted one with encrypted value of `last_name=Ferdinand` and another one with encrypted value of `last_name=Ferdadian`

I'd like to be able to search with a string and fetch both document as long as the levenstein distance is > 80 for example. Is this at all possible?

On another note, I also wanted to be able to do searches with 'like' over the encrypted data for example where `last_name like 'Fer%'`

Comment: I'll preface this by saying that I don't have a lot of experience with ElasticSearch, but just to be perfectly clear: do you want to search through the encrypted bytes?

Answer (score 1):

You can build index over encrypted data, but it would mean the data will be unencrypted in the index. The same reason why they are encrypted in the database itself likely means they can't be unencrypted in the elasticsearch index either.

And if the encryption is any good, similar values look completely different after encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Generally (not specific to Elasticsearch):

To search over encrypted data, you will need to decrypt it. If you want to make it fast, you need to keep a decrypted index. You can either have a fast search or good encryption but not both.